# Not able to validate external location because The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. error in Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse, external-tables

I've created a stored procedure in Synapse dedicated SQL pool, to load data from an external table(pointing to a Parquet file in Data lake) to a managed table in the same dedicated SQL pool. I'm able to execute the stored procedure without any errors in Synapse studio. But when I 'm trying to execute the same SP using Databricks , I'm getting the below error message

Not able to validate external location because The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.Can anyone help how to resolve this

Comment: can you provide the code that you have tried in databricks?

Comment: Does your SP has blob contributor or blob reader permission?

Answer (score 0):

> Not able to validate external location because the remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

It appears that the remote server is giving you trouble. The server is refusing access to the requested resource because the client is not allowed to do so, as shown by the error notice "The distant server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized".

- You might need to double-check the authorization details you're using to access the external data source in order to fix this problem.
- If you are using SAS token to authenticate, then check if it is not expired. When creating an SAS key, double-check that the Allowed resource category and Allowed access boxes are checked.
- As Alex said check your stored procedure has `Storage blob contributor role`, `blob reader role` . Try giving `storage blob data contributor role` to managed identity of Synapse workspace.

For me it is successfully executing synapse stored procedure from databricks.
[image]